# Getting coordinates of div in database

Tags: html, mysql, web

I am trying to make a site where you will be able to edit and drag the position of different divs. The position of these divs are saved in the database so that the user can load his/her custom UI anywhere. I already saved the position of the div yet i do not know how to load it from the database. can you please help me? thanks in advance. here is an example of my css code:

```
#two-columns #col1 {
top: <?php echo($x1);?>px;
left: <?php echo($y1);?>px;
width: 600px;
color: #FFFFFF;
overflow: visible;
}
```

this is my query:

```
<?php
$username=$_GET['username'];
$get_coords = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM '$coords' WHERE user_uname=$username");
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_coords)) {  
    $x1 = $row['x1'];  
    $y1 = $row['y1'];  
}             
?>
```

Comment: your sql query return all records, and `$x1` and `$y1` variables, after `while` loop has the value of last record.

Answer (score 0):

Each coords is connected to a specific user - I guess. So all you have to do is to make sure the sql query return  the associated recordset. 
You can do this by adding: `WHERE user_id = '$user_id';`

Allow me to suggest using prepared statements..

Comment: I tried adding this yet the div wont move. to the x and y position. :(

Comment: please update your question with more HTML code for us to get a better view of what you're working on. And I assume you have changed the column name into whatever you have in your table...

Answer (score 0):

I did a similiar project once. What I did was to save div attributes completely so I could add more attributes. Then I used it inline style. I stored it like

```
top:100px;left:5px;
```

and used it like

```
<div style="<?php echo ($attributes);?>"
```

Hope it works for you too